# how to active default ssl in openshift3 for running project on tomcat8?

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3

I deploy a .war file "Red Hat JBoss Web Server 3.0 Tomcat 8"  presented by openshift3 starter (step by step like this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tq55HW40rdA)).

It deployed and I can see my welcome page in browser with http url(this [sample](http://mywebapp-mrsalesi1-myopenshiftprj.193b.starter-ca-central-1.openshiftapps.com/))
But https is not available ([https of my project](https://mywebapp-mrsalesi1-myopenshiftprj.193b.starter-ca-central-1.openshiftapps.com/))

How to active default ssl to use https in openshift3 and tomcat for java web app?

How can I change config for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login in openshift 3 starter. In web console go to your project. Edit routs via applications>Routs (action>edit)

then check "Secure route" check box and then save that. may be it take some minutes.

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nsk-DeRm5GE)